# Represent the following numbers in normalised floating point

Tags: numerical-methods

Using an 8-decimal digit floating point
representation (4 digits for mantissa, 2 for
exponent and 1 each for sign for exponent
and sign for mantissa) represent the
following numbers in normalised floating
point from (using chopping if required)
(i) 92752
(ii) —93.231
(iii) —0.0012345

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: This seems a strange exercise, though perhaps it is designed as an early step in a method to gently ease the student into an understanding of floating-point numbers as they actually are represented in computer hardware. Why else treat a sign (which can have only two values) as a "decimal digit"? But I am mystified how one would "normalize" a **decimal** floating point representation. Also, who talks of "chopping"?

Comment: My advice would be to study the method that was taught to you. If you cannot see how to apply it to the exercise, you can edit the question to tell us everything that has been told to you about a some-number-of-decimal-digits normalized floating-point representation and explain what parts of it you find unclear and why. Maybe someone will see what was intended.